# Sync folder over network

Tags: python, ftp, synchronization

I've a software (in Python) that run in 25 PCs (10 with windows and 15 with Ubuntu). Sometimes I need to update that software.
So I need to sync a remote folder with the folder of that software in those 25PCs.
The software contains a server Python.

I was thinking about starting a process in the remote computer that send a message to all computers' servers  telling them to update.

At this point the server in every computer starts a process that sync its folder with the remote folder.

The problem is that I can't find anything for syncing 2 remote folder. I was thinking about python but I'm open to other ideas.

Is there some library that allows this? I need to oput an ftp server in the remote folder?

P.S. If the sync is a problem, it could be ok just to copy the folder.

Comment: why don't you make the program chk for a log text file on your server and they should download a new version of the file every time they start. if you have updated the log file all the programs will know what to do or you could hard code it for some specific words in the log file if they are true that means there is an update and they should download i did this once and it worked

Comment: Yes I was thinking at something similar, but when it check the version and it want to sync the folder, how can it do that? What library/function should I use?